# Embed an Image to Wasm for Uno Platform

Tags: xaml, uno-platform

How can I embed a different image rather than **"LockscreenLogo.png"** ?

I import my custom image which will be show on main page into "**Assets"** folder and make it embedded resource. After that, I add an **image component** and set its **source** to my custom image.

However, the image cannot visible on main page after building and **"view on browser"** option clicked. Image is not available in **"Assets"** folder.

How can I embed and show custom images with Uno Platform and Wasm ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Uno 2.0, embedded resource images cannot be referenced from an `Image` control for WebAssembly.

Images need to be set as `Content` build action, and can then be referenced with `Assets/myfile.png` (given those are placed in the `Assets` folder).

This is required for now because of the way files are handled by the mono runtime, and a future solution will most certainly be to use `Windows.Storage` WinRT APIs that support asynchronous access.